# Tensorflow 1.12 gives warning 'tf.estimator package not installed.' on import

Tags: installation, centos-7, pip, python3

On my machine, I am currently trying to get tensorflow to work, which I installed using `sudo pip3 install 'tensorflow-gpu==1.12'`. This installation looks like it succeeded, except that importing tensorflow in python3 now, gives the following warnings (or errors?):

```
$ python3
Python 3.4.8 (default, Mar 23 2018, 10:04:27) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow
tf.estimator package not installed.
tf.estimator package not installed.
```

This is quite weird, because when trying to upgrade it, pip gives me the following output:

```
$ sudo pip3 install tensorflow-estimator --upgrade
Requirement already up-to-date: tensorflow-estimator in /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages
Requirement already up-to-date: numpy>=1.13.3 in /usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages (from tensorflow-estimator)
Requirement already up-to-date: mock>=2.0.0 in /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from tensorflow-estimator)
Requirement already up-to-date: six>=1.10.0 in /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from tensorflow-estimator)
Requirement already up-to-date: absl-py>=0.1.6 in /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from tensorflow-estimator)
Requirement already up-to-date: pbr>=0.11 in /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from mock>=2.0.0->tensorflow-estimator)
```

After googling the error message I got, I found several suggestions telling me to install pandas, and some said to import pandas first, and only after that import tensorflow. After doing both of this, however, the same message persists on importing tensorflow.

Does anybody know how I can determine what the probem is with my installation, and how I might be able to fix the installation so that tensorflow works in its entirety?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was fixed, for some reason, by simply running `pip uninstall tensorflow-estimator`. Even though this way, estimator is not installed anymore, it no longer gives the same warning, and the code I wanted to run using tensorflow does run without errors now (which it did not before uninstalling it).

I'm sure this answer is not satisfying for any future googlers wanting to get estimator to work, so if you managed to get it to work without uninstalling, please do leave an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the tensorflow-estimator to 1.10.12 by doing `pip install tensorflow-estimator==1.10.12` and it resolved the issue.